# warning when partial matching rownames

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

I just tracked down a bug caused by partial matching of row names in a data frame. Is there a way to disable partial matching with the `[` operator or generate a warning when global matching is used? I know this is possible with `exact = TRUE` for the `[[` operator or with `options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)` for `$` indexing.

```
df <- data.frame(ab=1:4,cd=1:4)
rownames(df) <- paste0(letters[1:4],"a")
options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE) 
df$a      # warning!
df["a",]  # no warnig
```

Comment: Not right now, but the _next_ version of R will warn when partial matching happens with `$` on data frames: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html

Comment: I am surprised to see that rows use partial matching but not columns: `df[, "a"]` will error out. Looking at the code for `[.data.frame`, it does use `pmatch` where `if (is.character(i))`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable partial matching and I don't think there is a 1-line solution that will apply to all your code. One solution around the problem is to index rows not with characters, but with integer/logical vectors, e.g. replacing `df["a", ]` with `df[rownames(df) == "a", ]` in your code (or better yet, use `tibble`: `rownames_to_column(df) %>% filter(rowname == "aa")`).